# build boost for gcc using cygwin on Windows 7 - bootstrap error

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I downloaded boost and am doing this

```
admin@US01WKS03044 /cygdrive/c/Users/admin/Downloads/boost_1_49_0
$ ./bootstrap.bat gcc
Building Boost.Build engine
filent.c:35:21: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
 # include <direct.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
jam.c: In function ‘main’:
jam.c:181:25: error: ‘environ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     #define use_environ environ
                         ^
jam.c:417:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘use_environ’
         var_defines( use_environ, 1 );
                      ^
jam.c:181:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     #define use_environ environ
                         ^
jam.c:417:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘use_environ’
         var_defines( use_environ, 1 );
                      ^
jam.c: In function ‘executable_path’:
jam.c:628:18: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     if (argv0[0] == "/")
                  ^
pathunix.c:276:19: fatal error: tchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tchar.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
builtins.c:39:0: warning: "WIFEXITED" redefined
 # define WIFEXITED(w)  (((w) & 0XFFFFFF00) == 0)
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/cygwin/stdlib.h:14:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
                 from jam.h:89,
                 from builtins.c:7:
/usr/include/cygwin/wait.h:34:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define WIFEXITED(w) ((__wait_status_to_int(w) & 0xff) == 0)
 ^
builtins.c:40:0: warning: "WEXITSTATUS" redefined
 # define WEXITSTATUS(w)(w)
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/cygwin/stdlib.h:14:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25,
                 from jam.h:89,
                 from builtins.c:7:
/usr/include/cygwin/wait.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define WEXITSTATUS(w) ((__wait_status_to_int(w) >> 8) & 0xff)
 ^

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

Any suggestions on why I might be getting this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `bootstrap.bat` is for building Boost from the Windows command prompt in order to create a native Windows version of Boost. If you want to build a Cygwin version of Boost from the Cygwin shell you should follow the [instructions for building Boost on Unix-type systems](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).

Or as this message at the top of Boost's [Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) page says:

> **A note to Cygwin and MinGW users**
>
> If you plan to use your tools from the Windows command prompt, you're in the
>   right place. If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually
>   running on a POSIX platform and should follow the instructions for
>   [getting started on Unix variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).