# Build Boost1.61.0 with cygwin64 terminal in windows

Tags: c++, boost

I tried to build binaries of boost1.61.0 with cygwin64 terminal in windows10 today.I followed the [boost official instruction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) step by step and everything run normally until the last step   `./b2 install`
And then the system returned error message as follows:

```
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:107: in modules.call-in
ERROR: rule "<abi>ms" unknown in root module.
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/util/indirect.jam:98: in indirect.call
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:1054: in evaluate-requirements
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:1112: in common-properties2
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:977: in targets.common-properties
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:1303: in alias-target-class.generate
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0
/boostcpp.jam:432: in build-multiple
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0
/boostcpp.jam:394: in class@top-level-target.generate
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:774: in generate-really
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build/targets.jam:746: in class@main-target.generate
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/build-system.jam:714: in load
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/tools
/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/boost_1_61_0/
boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Here is the `bootstrap.log`:

```
###
### Using 'gcc' toolset.
###
rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
gcc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c
execcmd.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c
jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c
output.c parse.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c
timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c
class.c cwd.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c
modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c
modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c pathunix.c
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=gcc --toolset-root= clean
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
[DELETE] clean
...updated 1 target...
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=gcc --toolset-root=
...found 158 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
[COMPILE] bin.cygwinx86_64/b2.exe
[COPY] bin.cygwinx86_64/bjam.exe
...updated 2 targets...
```

The version of cygwin64 is 4.9.3

Could someone tell me what is happen and how to correct it?Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use boost all the time, but I never needed to install it. So I'm going to suggest my way, and you can pick and choose (note, I use msvc compiler normally, so I replaced every msvc with gcc for you, please correct me if I'm wrong. If you want to use msvc, remember to run msvc command prompt or run vcvarsall.bat before anything):

You run the bootstrap:

```
bootstrap.bat gcc
```

And then you compile:

```
b2 --build-type=complete stage runtime-link=static --toolset=gcc
```

Whether you want it static or not is your choice. Now then you create a *symbolic link* to where you want to have it. No need to install it anywhere.

Since symbolic links are obnoxious to create in Windows, I packaged some software that will make it easy with a simple right click. [Here you can download it](http://link.afach.de/easysym).

Comment: Thank you.But i tried this before and got an error message: fatal error direct.h: No such file or directory and more texts.

Comment: @Roaid I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181799/build-boost-for-gcc-using-cygwin-on-windows-7-bootstrap-error

Comment: Yes,I also found that before and that is the reason i try to build on cygwin64 terminal.

Comment: I figure it out.The cygwin64 is out-of-date.